# "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." as a result of The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Tags: php, azure, azure-sql-database

I am working with a php application deployed on Windows Azure.

I am running into an issue that results in the error:

```
"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."
```

when I look at the logs I see:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
```

The problem is that this happens when I want to get data from a sql server. When I try to post data to the sql server everything works fine.

The following code represents what I am trying to do with comments to explain what's happening:

```
try {
        // Try to connect to the database.
        $conn = new PDO ( "sqlsrv:server = server,1433; Database = name", "user", "password");
        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $conn->beginTransaction();
            // This works out when executed (I see the row in the table).
        $query = "INSERT INTO owner (email) VALUES ('email@email.com')";
        $conn->exec($query);
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT email FROM owner");
        $conn->commit();
        // If the SQL select is succesfully performed ($result not false)
        if($result !== false) {
            echo "there are results";
            // Traverse the result set and shows the data from each row
            foreach($result as $row) {
              echo $row['email']. '<br />';
            }
        }

        $conn = null;        // Disconnect
    } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        print( "Error connecting to SQL Server. Please call support!" );
        die(print_r($e));
    }
```

The code above does insert information in the table on the server but causes the error explained above. Please let me know if there is any more information that I can provide.

Answer (score -1):

Check access database credentials or maybe you have duplicate entry in database for `email@email.com`.
What is logged in error log?

Comment: maybe you have not installed pdo extension for php. I know how it can be done on linux, but not in windows azure(

Comment: the connection to the database does happen because I am able to add a row to the table ...